# How can I determine whether a temporary table exists

Tags: mysql, exists, temp-tables

How can I determine whether a temporary table exists?
I just need to determine, I do not need to create it.

The version is MySQL 5.6.

Comment: it is my error that i do not describe it sure.my aim is determine whether a temporary table exists in procedure.now i know the procedure sys.table_exists()  in MySQL 5.7 has achieved.

Answer (score 2):

`INNODB_TEMP_TABLE_INFO` provides information about user-created `InnoDB` temporary tables that are currently active within the `InnoDB` instance. It does not provide information about internal `InnoDB` temporary tables that are used by the optimizer.

so you can check using:

```
mysql>   SHOW TABLES FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA LIKE 'INNODB_TEMP%';
```

Query `INNODB_TEMP_TABLE_INFO` to view the temporary table metadata.

```
mysql>   SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.INNODB_TEMP_TABLE_INFO;
```

More detail is available [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-information-schema-temp-table-info.html)

Comment: This table is not available for MySQL 5.6.

Answer (score 1):

Dumping the database structure for all tables with no data

```
mysqldump -d -u someuser -p mydatabase
```

-d: no data, only structure

-u: username

-p: prompt for password later